# potential leak of an object allocated on line 82 and stored in data

Tags: objective-c, xcode

my Xcode 4.3.2 app terminates and raises an 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS' when i turned to product->analyze, it gives me the statement above, but i don't know how to resolve it, here's a screenshot below of the method having the problem demonstrates the situation, thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
CFDataRef cfData = (__bridge_retained CFDataRef)data;
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(cfData);    
CFRelease(cfData);
```

Comment: but the exception "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" is remaining, how come?

Comment: Analyzer shows a leaks, EXC_BAD_ACCESS indicates that you have a crash, there are few different things. EXC_BAD_ACCESS can appear in any line of your project. Try to enable NSZombie, it can help to find what object causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS.